# Cambiar diseño de formulario en flutter usando el plugin validators

Tags: formularios, flutter, validación, dart

Buenas tardes estoy creando un formulario el cual ya esta casi terminado. El plugin que estoy usando se llama **validators**. La cosa es que al validar los que hace el plugin es que cuando hay error, al input solo le cambia el borde de abajo a color rojo y yo quero que todos los bordes sean de color rojo.

Esta parte del codigo es donde mando a llamar el widget para los inputs

```
           InputForm(
              hintText: 'Motivo:',
              validator: (String value){
                if (value.isEmpty){
                  return 'Campo vacio';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onSaved: (String value) =>  widget.register.motivo = value,
              maxLines: 10,
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: CustomButton(
                'Enviar', 
                CustomColors.green, 
                (context) {
                  if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                    _formkey.currentState.save();
                    inspect(widget.register);
                  }
                }
              ),
            ),
```

La siguiente parte del codigo es donde creo el widget del input.

```
class InputForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hintText;
  final Function validator;
  final Function onSaved;
  bool isEnable = true;
  int maxLines;

  InputForm({Key key, this.hintText, this.validator, this.onSaved, this.isEnable, this.maxLines}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _InputFormState createState() => _InputFormState();
}

class _InputFormState extends State<InputForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.validator);
    final halfMediaWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.05;
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      width: halfMediaWidth,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: widget.hintText,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: CustomColors.blue),
            ),
            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: CustomColors.blue)
            )
          ),
          validator: widget.validator,
          onSaved: widget.onSaved,
          enabled: widget.isEnable,
          maxLines: widget.maxLines,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Este es el diseño del formulario el cual quiero que cuando hay error todo el borde del input que tenga error se marque en rojo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso mientras el campo esté vació el borde estará en red

TextField(
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

controller: _controllerCantidad,

textAlign: TextAlign.center,

decoration:

```
   InputDecoration(
           
            labelText:  "Cantidad total medicina",
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.post_add, color: Colors.blue),
            border:  OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.blue),),
            enabledBorder: _controllerCantidad.text.isEmpty ?
                OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.red),)
                : null,
            suffixIcon: _controllerCantidad.text.isEmpty 
            ? Container(width: 0,) 
            : CircleIconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                      _controllerCantidad.clear();
                },
            ),
     ),
```

);